# Elastic search not working as expected

Tags: php, elasticsearch, docker, client, kibana

I have used this query

```
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'should' => [
                ['match' => ['title'=> $q]],
                ['match' => ['year'=> $q]],
                ['match' => ['case_type'=> $q]],
                ['match' => ['body'=> $q]],
                ['match' => ['petition_no'=> $q]],
                ['match' => ['keywords'=> $q]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

and I don't know why I am not getting the right results. In docker ELASTICSEARCH log it shows this 
[WARN ][o.e.d.i.m.StringFieldMapper$TypeParser] The [string] field is deprecated, please use [text] or [keyword] instead on [title]
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a ES version which is above 5.x, then `string` data type has been deprecated FYI:

> The string field is unsupported for indexes created in 5.x in favor of
>   the text and keyword fields.

from the original [source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/string.html). You might have to create the fields, which consist of type `text` or `keyword` instead of `string` in your mapping.

Comment: So what am i should do now? should i keep this code intact and change my json file or what?

Comment: You have to change the data type of `string` on the fields you're having.  Yup that's right.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['title']
{$title= $_POST['title'];
$indexed =$client->index([
    'index'=>'cases',
    'type' =>'cases',
    'body'=>[
    'title'=>$title,]]
}


I am adding fields like this so how can i change the data type to text?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with php, but then before creating an index in ES you should be having a mapping which consists of the data types of the necessary fields. [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_index_management_operations.html#_create_an_index_advanced_example) might help you. Let me know whether it helps?

Comment: Its too complicated. Their example is going over my head as you see my code is like this "body"=>['title'=>$title]
which puts value of $title in title.
so if i want to set the type for it i'll have to go 'title'=>['type'=>'text']

But how am i going to insert the value in title this way?